# Blueprint CSS3, 3 column layout

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

I want to create a Blueprint CSS3 layout. with 3 columns.

I have the following:

```
<div id="hd" class="span-24 last">
        <div class=" span-7">
            1
        </div>
        <div class=" span-10">
            2
        </div>
        <div class=" span-7 bp-last">
            3
        </div>
</div>
```

problem is the 3rd column is under the 1st. Why is that? thx

Comment: can you show your css code also

Comment: I'm not so expirenced in blueprint but what is the `bp-last` for? I would use only `last`

Answer (score 1):

The class applied in 3th div should be "last", not "bg-last"

Answer (score 0):

That means your column widths plus margins add up to more than the total width of the hd div. Please post your css code also.